# How do I send my metadata xml file to the SAML SP I am connecting to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I built my SAML SP Metadata file using this site:
https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php

I then moved it to the cloud in a publicly accessible folder.

I set up my `appsettings.json` file like this:

appsettings.json:

```
"Saml2": {
    "IdPMetadata": "https://dev-15542.okta.com/app/hjy7ioye3dNVTjTTZ5r2/sso/saml/metadata",
    "Issuer": "MySPforSaml",
    "SignatureAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256",
    "SigningCertificateFile": "itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testwebappcore_Certificate.pfx",
    "SigningCertificatePassword": "!LOK5gst",
    "CertificateValidationMode": "None",
    //"CertificateValidationMode": "ChainTrust",
    "RevocationMode": "NoCheck",
    "samlMetadataUrl": "https://aws.amazon.com/test_sso/metadata.xml"
  }
```

And then I added the needed info to my `Program.cs` file.

Program.cs:

```
  builder.Services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(saml2Configuration =>
{
    saml2Configuration.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(saml2Configuration.Issuer);

    var entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor();
    entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(configuration["Saml2:IdPMetadata"]));
    entityDescriptor.ReadSPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(configuration["Saml2:samlMetadataUrl"]));
    if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor != null)
    {
        saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
        saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.AddRange(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("IdPSsoDescriptor not loaded from metadata.");
    }
});
```

However whenever I try to test it and connect, the IdP is saying it can't find the metadata file.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you create an SP (relying party) with the ITfoxtec Identity SAML component. The component should also create the SP metadata using the MetadataController like in this [ASP.NET Core sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/MetadataController.cs).

You should not read both ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl and ReadSPSsoDescriptorFromUrl. You application is either an SP or an IdP and should read the metadata from the opposite party.

Like this [SP sample read the IdP metadata](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L44).

Comment: Thanks, my app is an SP connecting to a SAML IdP.  The IdP admin says I need to send him metadata when my app makes the connection to his IdP.